# How to get current time of a particular country or UTC Time in Android (Kotlin)?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get the current time of a particular country or current UTC time regardless in which timezone I am in or what time I have set manually in the same timezone or different.

I want the current real time.

Answer (score 1):

You can get local time in Kotlin by importing so Java packages since Kotlin is interoperable with Java.

I.e.,

```
import java.util.*

fun main(){
    val currTime = Calendar.getInstance().time
    // To get TimeZone
    val timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().timeZone
    println(currTime) // Fri Nov 08 11:37:53 WAT 2019
    println(timeZone) // sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Luanda",offset=3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=3,lastRule=null]
}
```

This will produce:

```
Fri Nov 08 11:37:53 WAT 2019
sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Africa/Luanda",offset=3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=3,lastRule=null]
```

Another approach is by importing `import java.time.LocalDateTime`,
for example,

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime

fun main(){
    // Date and time
    val dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2016, Month.APRIL, 15, 3, 15)
    println(dateTime)

    // Date only
    val date = LocalDate.of(2016, Month.APRIL, 15)
    println(date)

    // Time only
    val time = LocalTime.of(3, 15, 10)
    println(time)
}
```

Output:

```
2016-04-15T03:15
2016-04-15
03:15:10
```

You can also use the following to get what you want:

```
// Current date and time
val dateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
println(dateTime)

// Curent date
val date = LocalDate.now()
println(date)

// Current time
val time = LocalTime.now()
println(time)
```

If you want to dive in deeper, check [this](https://www.ict.social/kotlin/oop/date-and-time-in-kotlin-creating-and-formatting) out.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import datatime

Korea = datetime.datetime.now()
```

And just print it in your program:

```
print(Korea)
```

You can also print datetime directly. The latter is slightly more accurate.